# How to ?$filter data using OData through WebAPI (PHP / cURL)

Tags: php, json, rest, curl, odata

I'm GETing data in JSON through a WebAPI by sending cURL requests to the server - basically works. Problem starts when I'm trying to filter for a field in (sorry, layman's terms) the 2nd layer of the JSON data.

Here's some example JSON data:

> {
>           "id": "SOMEHASH",
>           "name": "OPP-Name",
>           "actualCloseDate": "9999-12-31T00:00:00+01:00",
>           "companies": [
>               {
>                   "id": "SOMEOTHERHASH",
>                   "name": "Company Name"
>               }
>           ],

I'm trying to filter for the field "name" in the array "companies" (that's what I meant with 2nd level), but so far no luck. 
My URL to request the data including an OData filter looks like that right now:

> https://www.ourserver.tld/Opportunities/?$filter=Company/any(d:d/name eq 'Company Name')

but that only results in an empty response, as if no data were found (the name's a match for sure). To be honest, I don't understand the "d:d" part, just took that straight from the OData docs.

I tried

> https://www.ourserver.tld//Opportunities/?$filter=companies/any(name eq 'Company Name')

instead, but that throws a syntax error.
So, how to I form a correct request URL?

Comment: Hi, just wondering how did this go, I am trying to do something similat but I dont know where to start, I tought odata was just displaying the XML of the schema of the table but it seems is not just that

Comment: So far it didn't "go" at all. I'm currently working on filtering the data in my php code instead, which is anything but ideal, but it'll have to do for now. Sorry I can't be of any help.